# Trying to use javascript and json to store all the dog breeds from dog api site(https://dog.ceo/dog-api/) and storing them in a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

In my code what i tried to do was try and traverse over the keys of the object breedName and store it in an array, then i ran a loop through the array and tried to set the value of option and the inner text as the items in the array

Html:

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form >
        <label>Choose a Breed:</label>
        <select  id="select">
            <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
        
        
    </form>
    <button id="fetch-dog-image-button" style="margin: 10px;">Fetch Image</button>
    <div id="dog-image-container" style="margin: 20px;">
        <img id="dog-image">
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
    var keys = [];
var breedName = function fetchBreed(){

      $.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all', function(data){
         var breedName = data.message;
         
         
         for (var key in breedName) {
             if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                 keys.push(key);
             }
         }
         for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
             $("#select option").attr('value', key[i]);
             $("#select option").html(key[i]);
         }
         
        
    })
    
}
```

Please tell me where my code is wrong or how should i approach this, i am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your function from the button (onclick for example), then you need to create options and put them in your select:

```js
function fetchBreed(){
  $.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all', (data) => {
    const breedNames = data.message;
    const select = document.getElementById('select');

    for (const key in breedNames) {
      if (breedNames.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = key;
        option.innerHTML = key;
        
        select.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <button onclick="fetchBreed()">Fetch Breeds</button>
    
    <form>
        <label>Choose a Breed:</label>
        <select  id="select">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```